# table row, type something if input value change

Tags: jquery

> Good morning, how can it type "warning" in the  in
>   this table if class="hello" is > 100. I tried this:
>   $('#message').filter(function () {
>           return $.trim($(this).find('.hello').val())>100"}).text('warning!');

```
<table >
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;Year </td> 
    <td>&nbsp;2009</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;<input id="Text1" class="hello" value="Text1" name="Text1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;Month</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;2014</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;<input id="Text2" class="hello" value="Text2" name="Text2"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;Total</td> 
    <td>&nbsp;<input id="Text3" class="hello" value="Text3" name="Text3">&nbsp;</td>
  <td><p id="message"></p>&nbsp;</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I did this :
$('#message').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).find('.hello').val())>100"}).text('warning!');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more clear on what exactly you want and what you have tried, always add a Js fiddle example to show what you are trying and where you are stuck.

.filter() method in Jquery is used to reduce set of matched elements, i am not sure why you are using filter here , you have to bind change event for input fields and then check if input value >100.

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev, I've tried a lot of codes but it show the messages in all the rows. My table is not static

Answer (score 0):

@Tony: You should provide more information like when you want to run this validation, should it run when page loads or on change of input fields value?

If you want to validate input text when user types something and tab out then
you have to add change event handler in Jquery like below

```
$('.hello').on('change', function(){
        if( $(this).val()>100){
            $("#message").text('warning!');
        }
```

I have created a Js fiddle demo where the validation fires on input value change.
JS fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/S7jCL/2/

Comment: Thank you Sanjeev, using your code, it show "warning " in all the rows. My table is not static.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. *Please provide more information, So we understand your requirement.

As per my understanding-

> you want to show "Warning" message when user type greater than "100"
>   digit.

For this, you should need to bind the `input` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Bind change event to run the validation
    $('.hello').on('input', function(){        
        if( $(this).val()>100){
            $("#message").text('warning!');
        }   
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2yuj/)

OR you could use `.bind()` the `keyup` and `keydown` event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Bind change event to run the validation
   $('.hello').bind('keydown keyup',function(e){       
        if( $(this).val()>100){
            $("#message").text('warning!');
        }   
    });    
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2yuj/1/)

---

> You want to show "Warning" message when the length of text-box content greater than 100 character.

For this, we should use `.length`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Bind change event to run the validation
    $('.hello').on('input', function(){        
        if( $(this).val().length > 100){
            $("#message").text('warning!');
        }       
    });        
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L2yuj/3/)